# Selectize.js delegated event on option not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, selectize.js

I'm currently trying to listen to click events on generated options inside the dropdown, but I'm currently unable to achieve this.

Since options aren't generated when the DOM loads, I'm delegating the event to the document listening for clicks on the dropdown's options. My code currently looks like this:

```
var $accountsSelectize = $('#accounts-input').selectize({
  ...
});

$(document).on('click', '.accounts-input-selectize .option', function(event) {
  alert('An option was clicked!');
});
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. Any idea on why this is happening? Any clue regarding why this event isn't firing at all will be more than welcome.

Edit: Just an FYI, I'm adding a class to the HTML input element, that's why I'm listening for clicks on `.accounts-input-selectize .option`:

```
<input type="text" id="accounts-input" class="accounts-input-selectize" placeholder="Search accounts">
```

Comment: Isnt there an API `change` event in selectize? Why'd you need click event?

Comment: There is an API `change` event, but it doesn't fire if I'm clicking on an already selected option, which is why I need the click event, to check if the option was previously selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach to an admitedly half-baked "solution" is to create a plugin that intercepts the default event listener for clicks on options:

```
Selectize.define('click2deselect', function(options) {
  var self = this;
  var setup = self.setup;
  this.setup = function() {
    setup.apply(self, arguments);

    // Intercept default handlers
    self.$dropdown.off('mousedown click', '[data-selectable]').on('mousedown click', '[data-selectable]', function(e) {
      var value = $(this).attr('data-value'),
          inputValue = self.$input.attr('value');

      if (inputValue.indexOf(value) !== -1) {
        var inputValueArray = inputValue.split(','),
            index = inputValueArray.indexOf(value);

        inputValueArray.splice(index, 1);

        self.setValue(inputValueArray);
        self.focus();
      } else {
        return self.onOptionSelect.apply(self, arguments);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

The next step was to initialize Selectize using the previously created plugin, like this:

```
var $accountsSelectize = $('#accounts-input').selectize({
  plugins: ['click2deselect'],
  ...
});
```

And that's it.

Comment: Shooting birds with a canon )

Comment: Yet this is the only solution that worked for my case. If another, simpler, solution is proposed, I'd be more than happy to accept it as an answer.

Comment: How would you implement the onclick handler for this?

Comment: Your answer was very useful actually, thanks! I've changed your code somewhat to make the same sort of functionality.

@Ellisan I think one solution would be to do something like this within his setup function:

$(this).triggerHandler('click');

Answer (score 2):

The question sounds simple, but its not. The trouble is that selectize prevents all defaults, so at first I wouldn recommend using this lib, but still, if you really want to, there is a way to find out if user changed the option or not.

```
$('#select-country').selectize({

      //When user selects the widget we'll rememberize its value
      onFocus: function(){
        $(this).data('temp-saved', $('#select-country').val());
      },

      //On blur we check if the value has not changed
      onBlur: function(){
        var previous = $(this).data('temp-saved');
        var current = $('#select-country').val();

        if (current == previous) {
                console.log('NOT changed!');
        }
      },

      //And on change we sure that the value has changed
      onChange: function(current){
            var previous = $(this).data('temp-saved');
            console.log('changed from', previous, 'to', current);
      }
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mo1Ljm7r/13/

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm voting this up 'cause it might be useful for other folks out there, but this approach didn't work for me since I need to check _on click_ for values that are already selected (on blur or focus could work for other cases) but these events aren't fired when clicking on an option that's already selected. I'll be posting my approach to the solution in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

basing this off [NicolasJEngler's self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41559256/369717), I've made a microplugin that deselects the clicked-on option. The issue I ran into is this event always gets triggered after an option is added, so you can't tell if it already existed when clicked on. Therefore, I add a class to the option element when clicked/unclicked to check if it's newly added or not.

Hope it helps someone!

```
/* Selectize deselect function */
Selectize.define('click2deselect', function(options) {
    var self = this;
    var setup = self.setup;
    this.setup = function() {
        setup.apply(self, arguments);
        // add additional handler
        self.$dropdown.on('mousedown click', '[data-selectable]', function(e) {
            let value = this.getAttribute('data-value');
            if( this.classList.contains('checked') ) {
                this.classList.remove('checked');
                self.removeItem(value);
                self.refreshItems();
                self.refreshOptions();
            }else{
                this.classList.add('checked');
            }
        });
    }
});
```